# remove() in ArrayList

Tags: java, collections, garbage-collection

I am writing my own Array List. Here is the remove method of the same,

```
public E remove(int index){
        E value =(E) elementData[index];
        for(int i=index;i<size-1;i++){
            elementData[i]=elementData[i+1];
        }
        elementData[size-1]=null;
        return value;
    }
```

Now i will perform some remove operation

```
        Box<Integer> list = new Box<>();
        for(int i=1;i<5;i++){
            list.add(i);
        }
        print(list);
        list.remove(1);
        print(list);
```

Now this will result in the following output,

```
1 2 3 4

1 3 4 null
```

But when i use the ArrayList from the API, i will get the output as

```
1234

134
```

Am i missing something? Can someone please explain me where i went wrong.

Comment: I think you have to change the size as well.

Comment: You can also use `System.arraycopy` instead of a for loop. `System.arraycopy(elementData, index+1, elementData, index, size-index-1);
elementData[--size] = null;`

Comment: @ZouZou i saw that in API. Don't know how to see the native code.Can you please tell me how to see the native code. I am using Openjdk in linux machine.

Comment: The fastest way is to direclty check in [Grepcode](http://grepcode.com/). Or if you don't have an internet connection, all the sources are in the `src.zip` file in the top of your JDK installation folder.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess you need to update the `size` after `remove()` operation:

```
public E remove(int index){
    E value =(E) elementData[index];
    for(int i=index;i<size-1;i++){
        elementData[i]=elementData[i+1];
    }
    elementData[size-1]=null;
    --size;  // Decrement size
    return value;
}
```

You also need to be sure that `index` is in bounds of `elementData` array.

Comment: Thanq Rohit. I missed that. Thnx a lot for your quick response.

Comment: @RajuMandala Don't forget to accept the answer if it has helped you.